# Doing custom hover animation on nav items(bootstrap nav) but the effect isn't visible in my react application

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to add custom hover effect on my nav Items using ext CSS but when I import it in my Navbar the bootstrap isn't overwritten and the effect isn't visible and also when the navBar collapses the three  line isn't visible but when I click on the top right corner it's there and works fine

**

Here is my NAVBAR.JS file for react

**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import styles from './Navbar.css';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const links = [
  {
    href: '/novels/601e73a75e4fd540506c9938',
    text: 'Novel',
  },
  { href: '#', text: 'Buy EA Coins' },
  { href: '#', text: 'Get Started' },
  { href: '#', text: 'Library' },
  { href: '/', text: 'home' },
];

const createNavItem = ({ href, text, className }) => (
  <Nav.Item>
    <Nav.Link className={className}>
      <Link to={href}> {text}</Link>
    </Nav.Link>
  </Nav.Item>
);

class NavbarMain extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      key: 'home',
    };
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
  }

  handleSelect(key) {
    this.setState({
      key: key,
    });
    alert(`selected ${key}`);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar
        bg="light"
        variant="danger"
        expand="lg"
        fixed-top
        className={styles.test}
      >
    <Navbar bg="light">
      <Navbar.Brand>
            <Link to="/" exact>
              <img
                src="EA-Logo-edit.png"
                width="90"
                height="70"
                margin="none"
                className="d-inline-block align-top"
                alt="React Bootstrap logo"
                style={{ margin: 'none' }}
              />
            </Link>
          </Navbar.Brand>
        </Navbar>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
          <Nav className="mr-auto" activeKey="/" className={styles.avbar}>
            {links.map(createNavItem)}
          </Nav>

          <Nav className="ml-auto" navbar>
            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link href="#discord">
                <Button variant="outline-dark">
                  <img height={25} width={40} src="discord.svg" alt="" />
                  Discord
                </Button>
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link href="/auth/login">
                <Button variant="outline-dark">
                  <img height={25} width={40} src="google.svg" alt="" />
                  Login
                </Button>
              </Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
          </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

export default NavbarMain;
```

**Here is my CSS file**

```
:local(.navbar.hover::before){
position: relative;
}

:local(.navbar:before){
    content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

:local(.navbar:hover){
    color: #000;
}

:local(.navbar){
    position: relative;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: try to make your level of CSS specificity higher than the bootstrap. https://blog.hubspot.com/website/how-to-override-bootstrap-css

Answer (score 0):

You can fix overwrite problem with `!important` like this

```
:local(.navbar:hover){
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

Comment: but isn't !important a bad way of coding and is not preferred,

Comment: I do not think there is another way to overwrite if you are using bootstrap

Comment: do I use !important in every line or just the beginning of the class attribute, I'm new to CSS and react-bootstrap

Comment: You do not need to do for all, just for the parts that you can not change without !important

Comment: how to know which parts can't be updated without using !important is there any documentation that I can read?

Comment: Check on your frontend if it changes without !important or not then apply !important

Comment: I inserted !important everywhere and I also tried diff variations but it didn't work, am I inserting the CSS at the right place or is it something else